# Jquery event binding won't work when called as a method but will when called directly in console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a maddening problem. I have a table that contains rows consisiting of text inputs and selects. I have custom method I have definied that when called in the code, or in the console, it does not bind the click event any of the selects. Only the text inputs. However, if I copy and paste the code of the method directly in the console, it works just fine. Below is my code.

```
addEditHandler : function(){
                    $('#table2 .ui-icon-pencil').click(function(){
                            $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass("editing").find('input, select').removeAttr("readonly").css("background-color","white");
                            $('#table2 .ui-icon-disk').eq($(this).parent().parent().parent().index()).show();
                            $('#table2 .ui-icon-trash').eq($(this).parent().parent().parent().index()).show();
                            $('#table2 .ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s').eq($(this).parent().parent().parent().index()).show();
                            $('#table2 .ui-icon-pencil').hide();
                            if(addComponents.getCurrentComponents(getBOM.rawXML).size()>0){
                                addComponents.add();
                                addComponents.populateComponents();
                            }

                    });
                },
```

I am mostly focused on this main line:

```
 $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass("editing").find('input, select').removeAttr("readonly").css("background-color","white");
```

Calling this method doesn't apply the formatting to the selects, just the text boxes. Copying and pasting the EXACT code into the console does. At a loss.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its probably an issue with the scope of `this`. The difference between calling the code in the console vs the event is that in the console `$(this)` = `window` vs the click event `$(this)` = `$('#table2 .ui-icon-pencil')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A closer look at the debugger indicated that it was in face changing but was being changed back to it original state further on in the code because of a copy paste error. Can't image who would have done that. :)

Lesson learning, the debugger is your friend.